# Android Studio 3.1.3 error : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.api.internal.component.Usage

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I got the below log of my ide after updating all my android studio, gradle and gradle plugin to the latest version, after 6months on hold...

The SO answers on this subject didnt help to solve my issue.
Could someone help?

It is all the time a pain to go through the android periodic update process with bugs/errors jumping from everywhere...
-Pandroid.injected.studio.version=3.1.3.0 -Pandroid.builder.sdkDownload=false --init-script C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle  2018-07-29

> 02:47:24,210 [ thread 21]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver -
>   Gradle project resolve error  org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could
>   not run build action using Gradle distribution
>   'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip'.   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
>     ... Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException:
>   A problem occurred configuring project ':MyApp'.  at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
>     .... Caused by: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A
>   problem occurred configuring project ':MyApp'.    at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
>   ... Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not
>   resolve all dependencies for configuration ':MyApp:endpointsServer'.
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.wrapException(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:96)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:68)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$4.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:483)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:474)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:459)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1700(DefaultConfiguration.java:116)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getSelectedArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:901)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:889)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:404)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.endpoints.framework.client.EndpointsClientPlugin$1$1.execute(EndpointsClientPlugin.java:127)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.endpoints.framework.client.EndpointsClientPlugin$1$1.execute(EndpointsClientPlugin.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
>     ... 82 more Caused by:
>   org.gradle.model.internal.core.ModelRuleExecutionException: Exception
>   thrown while executing model rule:
>   PublishingPlugin.Rules#publishing(ExtensionContainer)     at
>   org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry.fireAction(DefaultModelRegistry.java:490)
>     at
>   org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry.access$700(DefaultModelRegistry.java:71)
>     ... more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/gradle/api/internal/component/Usage
>
> ... 132 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.gradle.api.internal.component.Usage   ... 177 more 2018-07-29
>   02:47:24,226 [ thread 21]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask -
>   Cause: org.gradle.api.internal.component.Usage 
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException:
>   Cause: org.gradle.api.internal.component.Usage    ... Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.gradle.api.internal.component.Usage   at
>   com.novoda.gradle.release.AndroidArtifacts.from(AndroidArtifacts.groovy:39)
>     at com.novoda.gradle.release.AndroidArtifacts$from$2.call(Unknown
>   Source)   .....   at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>
> 2018-07-29 02:47:24,257 [ thread 21]   WARN -
>   ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - Cause:
>   org.gradle.api.internal.component.Usage  2018-07-29 02:47:24,257 [
>   thread 21]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync
>   failed: Cause: org.gradle.api.internal.component.Usage
>
> Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (5s 456ms)

App Project gradle

```
>    buildscript {
>     repositories {
>         jcenter()
> 
>         google()
>     }
>     dependencies {
> 
>         // Endpoints Frameworks V2: Include this dependency when using Endpoints Framework v2
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0+'
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
>         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
> 
>     } }
> 
> 
> 
> allprojects {
>     repositories {
>         jcenter()
>         maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
>         mavenCentral()
>     }
> 
> 
>     tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {//this is for warning on backend: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
> 1 warning
>         targetCompatibility = '1.7'
>         sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
>         options.setBootClasspath("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\lib\\rt.jar")
>     } }
```

Main module gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-client'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        //maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

        google()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.github.nrudenko:gradle-android-cq-plugin:0.1+'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

       //Endpoints Frameworks V2: Add the new Endpoints Framework plugin dependencies
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
    } }

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://wordpress-mobile.github.io/WordPress-Android' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
    maven { url 'https://github.com/leonardocardoso/mvn-repo/raw/master/maven-deploy' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public' }
    jcenter() }


apply plugin: 'android-cq' apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {

    packagingOptions {
        exclude "META-INF/LICENSE.txt"
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude "META-INF/NOTICE.txt"
    }

    compileSdkVersion 26    // former working one "24.0.0 rc2"
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    productFlavors {
        // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
        dev {
            // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
            // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
            // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
            minSdkVersion 19
        }
        prod {
            // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
            minSdkVersion 16
        }
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26

        renderscriptTargetApi 24
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true 

/building/multidex.html
        multiDexEnabled true

        buildConfigField "String", "APP_PN_KEY", "\"org.wordpress.android.playstore\""
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt', 'proguard-google-api-client.txt'
            //   multiDexEnabled true
        }

        debug {

            buildConfigField "String", "APP_PN_KEY", "\"org.wordpress.android.debug.build\""
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false

        }

    }

   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'




    dexOptions {
        //maxProcessCount 4 // this is the default value
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false 
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
...
```

Comment: Please provide your project level gradle file

Comment: @HB, hi I edited above...i will first have a look at 'endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin' updates during these 6 past months as i feel there is some issue with endpoint server...thks

Comment: Hello how do you solve it?